# Prove that the set of continuous and bounded functions $f:\mapsto L(R^n,R^n)$ with the norm $d(f,g):=\sup{\|f(x)-g(x)\|}$ is a Banach Space.

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}$
Suppose that we have an interval $I$ in $\R^n$ and we consider $L(\R^n,\R^n)$ the set of all linear functions from $\R^n$ to $\R^n$. Prove that the set of continuous and bounded functions that go from $I$ in $\R^n$ to $L(\R^n, \R^n)$ is a Banach Space, with the norm $d(f,g):=\sup{\|f(x)-g(x)\|}$ , where $\|f(x)\|$ is the typical norm of a linear operator.

Could someone please help me?

Comment: The set of bounded continuous functions from a compact topological space into **any** Banach space $X$, is a Banach space.  The proof is exactly the same as when $X = \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: First of all: Welcome roberto. Please have a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation). There you can learn how to use mathjax to make your question look pretty and readable. Also notice please that "Could someone please help me?" Might be a bit to vague for this platform. It is not clear what you might need help with, right? If you don't get the question and/or don't even know where to start please also state this.